# Maintaining the state of my tree based navigation rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have got a tree based navigation which I want across various actions of a controller. However when I move to another action by clicking on the link_to, my tree based structure collapses.

How can I maintain the state?

Here is the code if it is needed:-

```
.three.columns
  %ul(class = "continent_name")
    - @destinations.group_by(&:continent).each do |continent, ds_per_continent|
      %li=link_to continent, "#"
      %ul(class = "country_name")
        - ds_per_continent.group_by(&:country).each do |country, ds_per_country|
          %li=link_to country, "#"
          %ul(class = "city_name")
            - ds_per_country.each do |destination|
              %li=link_to destination.name, destination_path(destination)
```

When I go to destination path I want the country name to be visible instead of everything collapsed. How can this be done?

**Controller Code**

```
class DestinationsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :find_destination, :except => [:index]
    before_filter :all_destinations

    def index   
    end

    def show
        @photos = @destination.destination_photos.all
        cookies['destination_id'] = params[:id]
    end

    def photos_videos
        @photos = @destination.destination_photos.all
    end

    def topic_blog
        @topics = Topic.all
    end

    private

    def find_destination
        @destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
    end

    def all_destinations
        @destinations = Destination.all
        cookies['destination_id'] = params[:id]
    end
end
```

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.country_name').hide();
    $('.city_name').hide();
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });

    $('.city_name').click(function(){
    $('.destination').append();
    });
});
```

**Model**

```
class Destination < ActiveRecord::Base

    alias_attribute :city, :name
    validates :continent,   :presence   => true
    validates :country,     :presence   => true

end
```

**Jquery**

```
$('.country_name').hide();
    $('.city_name').hide();
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });

    $('.city_name').click(function(){
    $('.destination').append();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cookies` method in your navigation controller. The node to expand should be registered in the cookie, e.g.

```
cookies['country_id'] = params[:country_id]
```

And then on the JS side, you could extract the node easily by using a `$.cookie` function available in the [cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), e.g.:

```
$.cookie('country_id');
```

Comment: Yep, there is an error in the controller code - I fixed it, hope now it works. Also I don't know how you navigation controller code looks alike, so I am not sure, which variable should be memoized in the cookie.

Comment: I am updating my question with controller code please have a look at it

Comment: I don't see the correspondence between the controller and the view. Also the jQuery/JS code that you use to expand the tree nodes would also help. Do you use any plugins?

Comment: Updated the code with JS code and model code, I am not using any plugins.

Comment: When I hover the mouse on the the tree node which takes me to the action say "show" in the destination controller it reads like localhost:3000/destination/id

Comment: You should remove `cookies['destination_id'] = params[:id]` from `all_destinations` - it sets the cookie to empty value, if the `:id` is not present in `params` and then check if the cookie is set, when you click the node, e.g. by `alert(get_cookie("destination_id"));`

Comment: I am getting an error in the function get_cookie on line 3, it says object destination_id =2 has no method find

Comment: jQuery has native support for cookies, so the get_cookie function is not needed. I updated the code - you can try it by writing `alert($.cookie('destination_id'));`.

Comment: I am getting uncaught type error in the js on line $.cookie('destination_id'), can we discuss it on chat?

Comment: Please join the room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8864/discussion-between-aleksander-pohl-and-dev-r

Comment: I dont know why it is so hard to implement I am really missing something very simple here

Comment: If you still need help with this code, I can help you a little bit. But it would be nice if you made the code available on github. That would make things much easier.